# How to open a form within non-GUI code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I write a program in Visual Basic, which doesn't need - and doesn't have - a GUI *unless* a certain event happens, in which the user needs to be involved (and a MsgBox wouldn't suffice).
Now I want to call a form (which I have already created in the project) from my code. So I want to call

```
Public Class MyForm
   {...} 'In my case empty
End Class
```

from within

```
Module MyMain
   {...} 'do unrelated stuff
   'Call MyForm somehow
   {...} 'proceed stuff, knowing users input
End Module
```

I see the form for a very brief moment, but I can't get my program to halt and wait for me, while I am in the form.
The code in my desperation is:

```
Module MyMain
   {...} 'do unrelated stuff
   Dim wifo As New MyForm()
   wifo.Show()
   wifo.Visible = True
   wifo.Activate()
   wifo.Focus()
   {...} 'proceed stuff, knowing users input
End Module
```

How does one do it?

Comment: `ShowDialog` stops execution until the form has been closed whereas `Show` carries on. So try `wifo.ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the Form.ShowDialog() method...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx